# Make dynamic form table with combobox use PHP mysql

Tags: php, mysql, combobox, dynamicform

I want to try make dynamic form table, with combobox from. But combobox can't show all record from where id specified.

My database contains 2 table:

**Table_Class**

```
| id_class| name  |
-------------------
|    1    |   A   |
|    2    |   B   |
|    3    |   C   |
```

**Table_Student**

```
| id_student | name  | id_class |
--------------------------------
|     1      | Sarah |    1     | 
|     2      | Joe   |    1     | 
|     3      | Yuri  |    2     | 
|     4      | Andy  |    2     | 
|     5      | Sam   |    3     | 
|     6      | Oliv  |    3     |
```

*id_class is foreign key

And i want result from those is a form interface as you can see in this image: 
[image]

But my code result is not what i want, combobox can not show all record from where id specified.

```html
<!--page-->
<table border="1">
 <thead>
  <tr>
  <th>Class</th>
  <th>Student</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
 <?php
 for ($x=0; $x <= (getCountClass()-1) ; $x++) {
 ?>
  <tr>
  <td>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="bobot" name="" value="<?php echo getClassName($x); ?>" readonly>
  </td>
  <td>    
   <select class="form-control">
    <option><?php echo getStudentName(getClassID($x));?></option>
   </select>
  </td>   
  </tr>
 <?php
 }
 ?>
 </tbody>
</table>

<!--function-->
<?php

function getClassID($no_urut) {
 include('config.php');
 $query  = "SELECT id_class FROM class ORDER BY id_class";
 $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  $listID[] = $row['id_class'];
 }

 return $listID[($no_urut)];
}

function getClassName($no_urut) {
 include('config.php');
 $query  = "SELECT name_class FROM class ORDER BY id_class";
 $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  $name[] = $row['name_class'];
 }

 return $name[($no_urut)];
}

function getStudentName($id_class) {
 include('config.php');
 $query  = "SELECT name_student FROM student WHERE id_class=$id_class";
 $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  $name = $row['name_student'];
 }

 return $name;
}

function getCountClass() {
 include('config.php');
 $query  = "SELECT count(*) FROM class";
 $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  $count = $row[0];
 }

 return $count;
}

?>
```

Sorry if my language is so bad, please help me solve this

Comment: you stated that you want to *"i want to try make dynamic form table"* .......... what have you tried and where is your code?

Comment: there's still zero code. Please show us your code. (html, php and Mysql)

Comment: Sorry if my ask way wrong, my question has been edited